# Firebase Analytics for User View in Android/Kotlin App

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

In My android application I am trying to achieve a page Where I want to show Some Graphs for Stats of App to Users Like Active Users , Avg Time Spent by all users who use the app, Global map indicating Users from which Country with Intensity or more

To what I know Firebase Analytics Provides such details but I think its only for Admin , That is only the people that have access to the project can view it

Is there a possibility of Bringing those Analytics Graphs , Data , Stats into the App to and Show the User ? I am trying to achieve this in Kotlin for a Android App.
Any Indicator or Clear Resource to read abt Would also be helpful With slight info on the part I am trying to Achieve.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could achieve this by using the [Google Analytics 4 Measurement Protocol API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4). The Measurement Protocol API allows developers to make HTTP requests to send events directly to Google Analytics servers. This allows you to measure how users interact with your business from any HTTP-enabled environment. Notably, this makes it easy to measure interactions that happen server-to-server.

You can use the Measurement Protocol on the following:

- Tie online to offline behavior.
- Measure interactions both client-side and server-side.
- Send events that happen outside standard user-interaction (e.g. offline conversions).

You can go to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4) for more information.